$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx\le 4 \int_0^1 x^2 f'(x)^2 dx$.
Problem
Assume $f(x)\in C^1[0,1]$ and $f(1)=0$. Prove $$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx\le 4 \int_0^1 x^2 f'(x)^2 dx.$$
Attempt
As per the conditions, we can have $$f^2(x)=\left(\int_x^1 f'(t)dt\right)^2\le \int_x^1 1^2 dt\int_x^1 f'(t)^2 dt=(1-x)\int_x^1 f'(t)^2 dt.$$
Integrating both sides over $[0,1]$, it holds that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f^2(x) dx &\le \int_0^1  (1-x)\int_x^1 f'(t)^2 dtdx\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_x^1 f'(t)^2 dt d\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\\
&=\int_x^1 f'(t)^2 dt \left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\bigg|_0^1+\int_0^1 \left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)f'(x)^2dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)f'(x)^2dx,
\end{align*}
the right hand side of which is not the one of the wanted.

Integrating by parts: $$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=xf^2(x)|_0^1 - \int_0^1 x (f^2(x))'dx=-2\int_0^1xf'(x)f(x)dx$$
By Cauchy-Schwartz (or Holder):
$$|\int_0^1 xf'(x)f(x)dx|^2\le \int_0^1(xf'(x))^2dx \int_0^1f(x)^2dx$$
Combined $$(\int_0^1f^2(x)dx)^2=4(\int_0^1xf'(x)f(x)dx)^2\le 4\int_0^1(xf'(x))^2dx\int_0^1f(x)^2dx$$
If $f\equiv 0$, the desired inequality holds trivially. Otherwise, $\int_0^1f^2(x)dx>0$, so we may divide it on both sides to get the result.

Thanks! But why does not my method  work?

I don't find anything wrong with what you did, but from what I did, we can see that equality holds iff $xf'(x)$ and $f(x)$ are linearly dependent. By solving the differential equation $xf'(x)=\alpha f(x)$, we know $f(x)=Cx^{\alpha}$ which cannot be $0$ at $x=1$ unless $C=0$. Hence the inequality is strict whenever $f\not\equiv 0$. However, in your method, the equality holds when $f'(t)$ is a constant. This makes it hard to compare the two results.
